# SQL - Conditional Join

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I'm looking to do an SQL join on some data. In a nutshell, I have a table (e.g. items_tbl) where users submit items for other users to bid on e.g.

```
itemUID, Details, Price, usernameOfSeller
```

And in another table (e.g. bid_tbl), I collect the bids

```
itemUID, usernameOfSeller, usernameofBuyer, offerPrice
```

What I wish to do is show the buyers every item they HAVE NOT bid on. Procueduraly it would be:

```
SELECT itemUID FROM bid_tbl WHERE usernameofBuyer = 'John'; //All the itemUID's John has bid on
```

And using this data set, select all the items he has not bid on from the other table:

```
SELECT itemUID FROM items_db WHERE itemUID <> [data from bid_tbl above]
```

I have done this 'joining' previously but never conditionally. Thank you!

**Basic Data Overview**

Sample items_tbl

```
1,Xbox,Sean,100
2,PS4,Mark,300
3,Xbox,Mark_b,500
```

Sample bid_tbl

```
/* John has bid on UID 1 and 2 */

1, Sean, John, 100
2, Mark, John, 200
```

Result Set:

```
/* John has not bid on itemUID 3 */

3
```

Comment: Don't name tables something_db, that will only confuse people!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Table name and fields are greatly simplified to try keep it clear for the purpose of the question. I'll make a quick edit now!

Comment: WHERE NOT EXISTS (correlated sub-select)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use sub-query with `NOT IN` clause, to exclude the items that were bid on:

```
SELECT itemUID FROM items_db 
WHERE itemUID NOT IN 
    (SELECT itemUID FROM bid_tbl WHERE usernameofBuyer = 'John')
```

Another way would be to user `LEFT JOIN` and filter out the items that actually have left join:

```
SELECT i.itemUID 
FROM items_db i LEFT JOIN bid_tbl b ON i.itemUID = b.itemUID AND b.usernameofBuyer = 'John'
WHERE b.itemUID IS NULL
```